# update-grub assigns old UUID

Tags: boot, grub2, uuid

I moved my Ubuntu partition following [these steps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition) and mostly everything went OK. I had to use some tools to fix some stuff but anyway, Ubuntu and Windows 10 boots fine.

**The problem is that whenever I use `update-grub`, the old UUID that this Ubuntu used is used instead of the new one.** And I have to go and manually edit the grub.conf file with a live USB to put the correct UUID and be able to boot from grub2 again...

Where is this old UUID stored and how can I change it to the new one so grub-update functions properly?

**EDIT:** I want to clarify that the old partition is already deleted so there's no other Linux partition in my system to detect.

Comment: What is grub-update? Do you mean  `update-grub`?

Comment: Oops, yes! I was typing from memory. It's fixed now!

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it myself after doing a grep search for the UUID.

Turned out that `/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/custom` had the old UUID, after replacing them with the new one, `update-grub` generated correctly with the proper UUID.

If someone could comment on why that happened or how to avoid this for other people would be very helpful. :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Something to do with the grub customizer you ran. It backs up standard grub scripts and creates its own with _proxy at end. Did you then also manually edit 40_custom?

Comment: @oldfred no, i don't have a 40_custom file, I have 40_custom_proxy, tho.

Comment: And yes, I used Grub `grub-customizer` to edit grub, that caused the issues as it created custom files?

Comment: I do not use grub customizer, but believe that is the issue. I prefer just to make what changes I want myself to grub, but some learning curve. But many find grub customizer easier to use. You have to do a total reinstall of grub to convert grub back to defaults, but then lose any changes you made.